# "My prescience is unerring" vs. "In my prescience, I am unerring"

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, subjects

I am writing dialogue for a '70s / '80s style text adventure I hope to develop. I would like to use option A, but it seems less grammatical than option B. The difference, of course, is the subject.

**Can an ability be unerring, or only a person/group? Does A get the point across, or is it safer to use B?**

Option A:

> *"My prescience is unerring..."*

Option B:

> *"In my prescience, I am unerring..."*

Comment: The first is more colloquial, to me, and just as clear. Of course, I knew that answer *before* you asked ;-)

Comment: @DrMoishePippik And you did not err. But you knew that.